# How can I extract the username from logs in Kibana query and save into a separate field?

Tags: kibana, kibana-7

I'm a bit of a newbie on ECE/Kibana, having used splunk in the past and having an issue with extracting the data I need.

For the application in question, Im getting som logs in the following format:

```
[loggerName] [<ip of caller>] [sessionId] - USER <username>
```

Now, I would like to extract the username into it's own field, and make a nice visualization with it.

I have seen that I can do this with a runtime-field, but this would run for EVERY search that is performed for my index (tried that, was abysmal for our search performance). I would like a way to just map it to a field for 'this' query, and it's lens/visualization. Aka, pipe the result to another stage to fine tune the data.

With splunk, I could do this with a rex (regexp parsing) and pipe it to a table-command.
And from a logfile, I'd just | 'grep -o' or use some awk-thing..

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
POST test_parse_logs/_bulk?refresh
{ "index" : { "_id" : "1" } }
{ "message": "[loggerName] [<ip of caller>] [sessionId] - USER username" }

PUT _ingest/pipeline/parse_username_pipeline
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "grok": {
        "field": "message",
        "patterns": [
          "- USER %{USER:username}"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

GET test_parse_logs/_search
```

> result: "message": "[loggerName] [] [sessionId] - USER
> username"

**#update existing data use _update_by_query API**

```
POST test_parse_logs/_update_by_query?pipeline=parse_username_pipeline

GET test_parse_logs/_search
```

result:

> ```
>     "_source": {
>       "message": "[loggerName] [<ip of caller>] [sessionId] - USER username",
>       "username": "username"
>     }
> ```

**For the new data, set the ingest pipeline as `default pipeline`.**

```
PUT test_parse_logs/_settings
{"default_pipeline":"parse_username_pipeline"}

POST test_parse_logs/_bulk?refresh
{ "index" : { "_id" : "2" } }
{ "message": "[loggerName] [<ip of caller>] [sessionId] - USER musab.dogan" }

GET test_parse_logs/_search
```

[ingest pipeline official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But with this approach, I'd update my index with this new field, set by the needs of only this one service, would I not?  
I don't wish to set this generally, since different services logs, unfortunately looks slightly different but are indexed to the same index.

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't understand what are you talking about. Can you a bit clarify?

Comment: So, we have several different services running which report logs to the same index... So I would like to have a query extract the data I need, without updating indexes, runtime fields etc. For this pattern is only valid for one of the services not all... 

Maybe we should rethink our  strategy, but right now, this is what we have..

Answer (score 0):

So, some more work with this and I found a solution that maybe did not take me all the way, but it did give me the information I needed, although not in a pretty table in Lens.

From my query in Discover, I could get that with me to the dev-tools console through inspect.

There, I could add a script under runtime_mappings:

```
"runtime_mappings": {
    "myUsername": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "script": {
        "source": """
        if (doc['message.keyword'].size() != 0 && doc['message.keyword'].value.contains('- USER')) {
            emit(doc['message.keyword'].value.splitOnToken('- USER ')[1])
          
        }
        """
      }
    }
```

Unfortunately, I could not find a way to then use this to create a nice Visualization (could probably be done with Vega), but I did get the data I needed through an aggregation at the end.

```
"aggs": {
    "users": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "myUsername",
        "size": 100
      }
    }
    
  }
```